# Animation jumps during NavigationLink transition

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-animation

I was trying to do a simple navigation between two views programmatically using NavigationLink, but I'd like the navigation transition to fade as opposed to sliding in from the right. I do this with these modifiers around the NavigationView:

```
NavigationView {
// welcome screen UI code
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
.navigationTransition(.fade(.out).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.9)))
```

For some reason, after the navigation occurs, the pulsing animation jumps. Here's a [5 second video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dZ36QQECF2xYFsk4uHcebXLySTPtuVhm/view?usp=sharing) showing the jump.

Forgive my extremely crappy code (this is just a prototype), but here's the [code of the SwiftUI view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdqVf.png) that animates the dot using `scaleEffect`.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is there some better way to start the animation so it doesn't lag?

The strange thing is that when I transition from the start screen to the dot screen without a navigation, there is no jump. Why does it only jump when I navigate?

```
if appViewModel.state == .newUser {
   StartScreenView(appViewModel: appViewModel).transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)))
else {
   RecordingView().transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)))
}
```

Comment: Hi @drainmond and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a a [mcve] to make it easy for people to recreate your problem. Just add the minimal code that can be run to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: try using .animation(.spring(), value: buttonScale) on the highest view in the hierarchy instead of withAnimation